# Attachment not working in Microsoft Team: Bot framework v3

Tags: c#, botframework, botconnector, microsoft-teams

I am writing a bot using C# and I'm able to see a png image in Emulator, but in Microsoft Teams chat, it's showing like not found image path.

Here is the simple reply attachment bot code:

```
message.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();
                            message.Attachments.Add(
                                new Attachment()
                                {
                                    ContentUrl = "https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/images/faq-overview/botframework_overview_july.png",
                                    ContentType = "image/png",
                                    Name = filteredPolicy.Filename
                                }
                            );
                            await context.PostAsync(message);
```

**Reference:** Screen shots of my both Bot Emulator and Microsoft't Team

[Bot Emulator showing image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYspB.png)

[Microsoft team not displaying image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dm0pC.png)

**Note:** Even for PDF attachement, the emulator it's showing pdf file link, but not Microsoft Team.

Comment: To send pdf/doc link to the user,I have achieved it by `string messageText = "![Sample Image](http://aka.ms/Fo983c)";
await context.PostAsync(messageText);`

Comment: We're unable to recreate this issue. This code is virtually identical to the SendAttachmentBot sample, and even when modifying that to mimic your code (except for your *Name*) we're seeing the image in both the Emulator, Client and Web version. Are you still seeing the issue?

Comment: @RichMoe-Microsoft I'm facing a similar issue while trying to show an excel attachment (ie: ContentType = "application/excel") in Teams. Do we have any workaround for this one ?